# topics that create a loop

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,
I have two nodes both of which publish    different custom defined messages. Node A publishes message A , and Node B publishes message B.
Can node A subscribe to message B while node B subscribes to message A.
I am getting error a fatal error saying that the  No such file or directory for the custom defined message.
When i disable node B's subscribing the message A, node can successfully publish the message B.
Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43821/topics-that-create-a-loop/) by [searchrescue](https://answers.ros.org/users/1542/searchrescue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to make topics go in a loop as described. It isn't possible to declare circular dependencies between packages.

It sounds like you have a typo or have forgotten to include a package dependency somewhere.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2